# Salvando arquivo csv utilizando python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Eu tenho um arquivo csv  com vários números.

Eu leio esse arquivo, passo um cabeçalho e faço a separação
O problema acontece quando eu tento salvar esses dados em um novo arquivo csv.

A separação não ocorre e acaba ficando igual ao arquivo anterior antes da edição

Segue o código que eu fiz:

```
import pandas as pd

uri = "dados.csv"

cabecalho = ['Axis1', 'Axis2', 'Axis3', 'Steps', 'Lux', 'Inclinometer Off', 'Inclinometer Standing', 'Inclinometer Sitting', 'Inclinometer Lying']


dados =  pd.read_csv(uri, sep=',', header=None, names=cabecalho, index_col=0)
dados.to_csv('dadosLimpos.csv', sep=',')
```

Exemplo do CSV:

```
489,768,860,3,28,0,10,0,0
644,796,684,7,56,0,10,0,0
1219,1294,1721,7,74,0,10,0,0
495,770,556,3,22,0,10,0,0
74,241,386,2,0,0,10,0,0
1153,781,837,7,63,0,10,0,0
191,365,382,2,55,0,10,0,0
27,733,185,1,73,3,0,0,7
7,554,114,1,98,8,0,0,2
213,974,574,4,96,0,10,0,0
```

Comment: A intenção era criar o cabeçalho no novo arquivo e manter os números?

Comment: Sim. O cabeçalho vem normal, mas ele não separa os numeros corretos em cada coluna. Ficam todos salvos no "Axis1".

Comment: Coloca o CSV que você está utilizando, fiz um teste e ficou tudo certinho, não alterei nada no seu código. Se o CSV for muito grande, coloca apenas um trecho, algumas linhas.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com alguns dados do csv

Comment: É esse o resultado esperado? https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8U71.png

Comment: É nesse formato mesmo.

Comment: Então, não alterei nada... Se tá abrindo esse CSV gerado onde? No Excel?

Comment: Sim. Ele salva com esse novo nome e eu abro ele

Comment: Maick, isso é só o Excel mesmo, ele está interpretando o CSV com o delimitador sendo ponto e vírgula, acredito que seja o padrão na instalação BR. Infelizmente no momento não tenho um Excel pra te orientar como trocar isso, mas se quiser fazer um teste, troque a vírgula do csv por ponto e vírgula e abra novamente.

Comment: Eu tinha feito esse teste. Troquei todas as virgulas por ; . O cabeçalho ele separou certinho, coluna por coluna, menos os números. Vou tentar ver as configurações dele aqui. Mesmo assim muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O código funciona como desejado, o problema deve ser a configuração de delimitador do excel (Utiliza `;`).

É possível abrir o arquivo em um editor de texto e usar a opção de encontrar e substituir.

Substitua `,` por por `;`

Assim o excel deve abrir o arquivo corretamente

Para outro programa como LibreOffice não é necessário fazer nada

Answer (score 0):

Você pode gravar o arquivo de saida diretamente no formato `.xlsx`.

Primeiro instale o módulo `openpyxl`:

```
$ pip3 install openpyxl
```

Agora, use o seguinte código:

```
import pandas as pd

entrada = 'dados.csv'
saida = 'dados_limpos.xlsx'
planilha = 'Planilha1'

cabecalho = ['Axis1', 'Axis2', 'Axis3', 'Steps','Lux', 'Inclinometer Off',
    'Inclinometer Standing','Inclinometer Sitting', 'Inclinometer Lying']

df = pd.read_csv(entrada, sep=',', header=None, names=cabecalho, index_col=0)

gravador = pd.ExcelWriter(saida)
df.to_excel(gravador, planilha)
gravador.save()
```

Arquivo de Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]